# Error 110 Invalid Cookie in Request Dialog

Tags: c#, ios, facebook, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm using Facebook SDK for iOS in Xamarin (MonoTouch.FacebookConnect).  I'm creating a request dialog using the following API.  But I'm getting an error.  I have this code:

```
parms = NSMutableDictionary.FromObjectsAndKeys(
    new NSObject[] 
    { 
        new NSString(id), 
        new NSString(userid),
        new NSString(token))
    }, 
    new NSObject[] 
    { 
        new NSString("to"), 
        new NSString("id"),
        new NSString("token") 
    });

FBWebDialogs.PresentRequestsDialogModally (
    null,
    "Come join my challenge.",
    "Come Play",
    parms,
    (FBWebDialogResult result, NSUrl resultUrl, NSError error) => 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("within handler");
    }
);
```

And when it opens up the request, I get the following error:

```
An error occurred.  Please try again later.  
Error Code 110 
Error Description: Invalid user id
Error Message: Missing user cookie (to validate session user)
```

I am using the MonoTouch FacebookConnect FBLoginView control to manage the logging in process.  However, I cannot properly establish the request.  Any idea why?  Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to make sure the Native iOS App option is checked, and that the bundle identifier is specified for the application (which is setup on the developer.apple.com site under certificates, identities, and profiles).  Once I configured it, the request now pops up without getting this error.